# Parse - How to insert data on parse server using REST Api using javascript?

Tags: rest, parse-platform

I am integrating parse rest api to insert data on a table using jsp page. and using following code in javascript -

```
var headers = {
        "X-Parse-Application-Id" : "myparseappid",
        "X-Parse-REST-API-Key" : "myparserestapi"
    };

    // Variable to store data:
    var userData = {
        "name" : "anyname"
    };

    var data = JSON.stringify(userData);

    // Send data:
    $.ajax({
                    type : "POST",
                    url : "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/MyClassName",
                    data : userData,
                    contentType : "application/json",
                    headers : headers,
                    dataType:"json",
                    success : function(data, status, xhr) {
                        alert("data:" + JSON.stringify(data) + " status: "+ status);
                        if (status === "success") {

                            // Show success feedback:
                            alert("Data was saved successfully");

                        } else {

                            // Show error message:
                            alert("Your data didn't save. Please check that you are online. Status: "
                                            + status);
                        }
                    },
                    error : function(data, status, xhr) {

                        // Show error message:
                        alert("Your data didn't save. Please check that you are online. Status: "
                                        + status);
                    }
                });
```

and for ajax i called following js -

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

Question - It is not saving the records whats wrong with above code. please suggest me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the current output? Is either one of the success or error callback executed?

Comment: error callback executed.

Comment: Can you paste the value of data and status vars when that callback is run?